# What is the final message conveyed by Shvetashvatara Upanishad?

Tags: upanishads

Upanishads are long texts. So it is useful to know to know the final message and implement the same in our day to day life.

Comment: Upanishads are not at all long texts with the exception of Chandogya and Brihadaranyaka. The rest are quite short texts.

Comment: You should limit your question to a specific topic. Asking whole message is too broad and will be closed.